# Reorder display of hypothesis in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Is there a tactic to reorder the display of hypothesis within a Coq proof. Very often while using induction (the hypothesis are very long) and I would like to print all definitions at the top and all other equations together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify, Coq does come with tactics to reorder hypotheses.
These are [listed in the documentation](https://coq.github.io/doc/v8.12/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.move-after)

Namely you will be interested in

```
move h before h'.
move h after h'.
move h at top.
move h at bottom.
```

The documentation comes with useful examples, but the names should be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing shipped with Coq, but Pierre Courtieu's [LibHyps](https://github.com/Matafou/LibHyps) provides some facilities for this. In particular:

```
Require Import LibHyps.LibHyps.
onAllHyps move_up_types.
```

should perform what you are looking for.